# How to move focus when error in bound field?

Tags: vb.net

I have VB.Net Application with some fields bound to a datatable.

Here is my code :

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load 

    Me.DxErrorProvider1 = New DevExpress.XtraEditors.DXErrorProvider.DXErrorProvider(Me.components)
    Dim DT As DataTable = GetDT()
    Me.TextEdit1.DataBindings.Add("EditValue", DT, "C1", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation, "")
End Sub

Function GetDT() As DataTable
    Dim DT As New DataTable

    Dim i As Integer = 0
    DT.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("C1", i.GetType))

    Dim R As DataRow = DT.NewRow
    R.Item(0) = 15
    DT.Rows.Add(R)

    Return DT
End Function
```

When the user types a wrong value on the field. The focus can not move anymore.

The full code contains actually multiple fields and I would like to allow the user to be able to move the next field even if there is wrong value. A red icon shows, so he may want to correct it later.

Is there anyway to achieve that please ?

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot commit the new data to the underlying `DataRowView` if the data isn't valid. In order to prevent, the data being attempted to be committed, I would think that you'd have to change the `DataSourceUpdateMode` of the relevant `Binding` to `Never`. You'd then have to handle validation when the control lost focus yourself if you wanted it and then call `WriteValue` on the `Binding` when you wanted to commit the change.

Comment: Actually I do not want to commint the new data. I just want to move focus to another field and make it with an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution :

```
Me.AutoValidate = Windows.Forms.AutoValidate.EnableAllowFocusChange
```

Answer (score -1):

I was thinking arround and i figured this get-through, i hope it helps some how.

```
        AddHandler TextEdit1.LostFocus, Sub()
                                            If TextEdit1.ErrorText <> "Focus released" And TextEdit1.ErrorText <> ""  Then
                                                TextEdit1.DataBindings(0).DataSourceUpdateMode = DataSourceUpdateMode.Never
                                                DxErrorProvider1.SetError(TextEdit1, "Focus released")
                                            Else
                                                DxErrorProvider1.SetError(TextEdit1, "")
                                                TextEdit1.DataBindings(0).DataSourceUpdateMode = DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged
                                            End If
                                        End Sub
```

Also you can add `TextEdit1.BackColor = Color.red` or `TextEdit1.BackColor = Color.Empty` in either of both IF segments

Comment: What about if the langaguge of the user is not english ? "Invalid Value" wont be recognized... The solution is quite simple : Me.AutoValidate = Windows.Forms.AutoValidate.EnableAllowFocusChange

Comment: @ThomasCarlton i just feel fine to leave this in case the coder doesn't want to leave his mother-form's focus control unbound.